# Using getDate function on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an advent calendar app, set up so when you click on a door it selects a random image.  I want to wrap that in a getDate function so you can only 'open' that door on a specific date.  I have no idea where to begin, any help would be appreciated - I am pretty new to JS

Link: http://p3.katecooperuk.com

My HTML:

```
<div id='calendar'>
<div class='doors' id='dec1'>1</div>
<div class='doors' id='dec2'>2</div>
<div class='doors' id='dec3'>3</div>
<div class='doors' id='dec4'>4</div>
<!-- etc... --!>
<div class='doors' id='dec24'>24</div>
</div
```

My JS:

Set Up Splice to select random image and ensure it's only used once

```
function getRandomImage(arr) {

    if (arr.length > 0) { 
    random = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
    return arr.splice(random, 1)[0];
    } 

}
```

Setup Date

```
var today = new Date()
var day = today.getDate()

console.log(today);
```

Door Open - select Random background image from Array

```
$('.doors').click(function () {

    if (today.getMonth() !== 11) {
        return;
    }

    if ($(this).attr('id') <= 'dec' + day) {

        // Select Random Image
        var doorImage = getRandomImage(calendarImg); 

        // Change background image of door that was clicked
        $(this).css('background-image', doorImage);

        return;  
    }

    // Show image telling user to come back
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/images/come_back.png)');

});
```

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow isn't a place where developers do the code for you. Ask nicely about a specific problem, and you'll receive an answer (if someone knows it, of course).

Comment: so you want to allow users to open a door only if is the the day om `day`? ie on `Dec 05` you want to allow users to opne only `dec5` door

Comment: Arun, thank you for responding and that's exactly what I want. I'm not asking for developers to do the code for me. I just don't know where to start and am asking for help (I thought I did ask nicely?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to attach the onclick handler only to the "door" of the day instead of all "doors". You have current date and good `id`s for the "doors" already, just use them like this:

```
$('#dec' + day).click(function(){...});
```

---

**EDIT**

Looks like you've changed your code in the post. If you want to tell user about clicking a wrong door, the code above can't be used. Do something like this instead:

```
$('.doors').click(function () {
    if (today.getMonth() !== 11) {
        return;
    }
    if ($(this).attr('id') !== 'dec' + day) {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/images/come_back.jpg)');
        return;
    }
    // show the image
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVgAh/).

Comment: You're wellcome. Please also accept the answer, if it has been helpful.

Comment: Teemu, sorry to ask for more help, working on your suggestion I have updated the code but I'm having some trouble with the identifier

Comment: thank you, i've fixed the code as you suggest and added a 'dec30' div so I can test it but it's still not working and throwing out an 'Uncaught error' on the console.

Comment: Thanks Teemu, I really appreciate the time you have spent on helping me with this.  I've updated my code as you suggested and changed the month to '10' so I can test it today but it's still not working.  I've updated my original code to illustrate

Comment: @snooks I've added a fiddle link to my answer, please check the fiddle, maybe you can find what went wrong in your code. The fiddle responses to console, current day is set to 20. Nov.

Comment: I am using the code as you suggested but have altered it slightly so that if the date is today or less you can open doors from today or before today - it is sort of working but still opening doors from 10 - 19.  I have updated my code above to illustrate

Comment: @snooks Comparing characters leads unexpected results, use numbers instead, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dVgAh/2/).

Comment: thank you again @Teemu, this one really confused me, i've learnt a lot :)